# Dealing and comparing values which could be nulls c#

Tags: c#

What is a better way of doing the following. The below will work however its very long winded and cumbersome.  The `switch` statement will assign values to certain variables but not all.

```
        string status = null;
        string proceedure = null;
        string Type = null;
        string lastDonationDate = null;
        string actualStatus = _pageManager.BrowserDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ddd")).Text;
        string actualProceedure = _pageManager.BrowserDriver.FindElement(By.Id("dd")).Text;
        string actualType = _pageManager.BrowserDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ddd")).Text;
        string actualLastDonationDate = _pageManager.BrowserDriver.FindElement(By.Id("ddd")).Text;


        switch (campaign)
        {
            case "Newsletter":
                status = "Active";
                proceedure = "qweqwe";
                break;
            case "Famaily":
                break;
            case "Family":
                break;
            case "Priority Donor ":
                break;
            case "Birthday":
                break;
            case "Freshers":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (status != null)
        {
//compare code here
        }
        if (proceedure != null)
        {

        }
        if (type != null)
        {

        }
        if (lastDonationDate != null)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Can you show us what is actually in the if statements?

Comment: Do you really have a bunch of empty `case` statements?  If so, that entire `switch` can just be an `if`.

Comment: @juharr No, I will populate them.

Comment: @Sweeper just an Assert.AreEqual

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator `?` like

```
status = (campign == "Newsletter") ? "Active" : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The `??` operator

If you are trying to use values which could be nil and want to use a default value if the value is indeed nil, you can use the `??` operator.

This code:

```
if (status != null)
{
    somethingElse = status;
} else {
    somethingElse = "Error";
}
```

Can be simplified to:

```
somethingElse = status ?? "Error";
```

#### The `?.` operator (C# 6 and above)

If you are accessing a member of a value that might be null, you can use `?.`.

This code:

```
if (status != null)
{
    status.SomeMethod();
}
```

can be simplified to

```
status?.SomeMethod();
```

`SomeMethod` will not be called if `status` is null.

---

Apparently you are doing an `Assert.AreEqual` call. Well in that case you will probably use the `?.`. You might do something like:

```
Assert.AreEqual(status?.Substring(0, 2), "Er");
```

`status?.Substring(0, 2)` will evaluate to null if status is null, which will in turn cause an `AssertFailedException`. If you don't want this exception if `status` is null, try using `??`:

```
Assert.AreEqual((status ?? "Error").Substring(0, 2), "Er");
```

If status is null, the assert will succeed.

Comment: later one `?.` is only possible if running *C#6* .. probably you should mention that as well